# Why does bitcoin-cli return strange version numbers for blocks?

Tags: block-header, bitcoin-cli

I've been looking at the version numbers of blocks, but I'm getting strange results from **bitcoin-cli getblock**.

```
"version": 536870913
```

However, when I run the same command with the `false` option (to get the serialized block data), it shows a version number of `1`:

```
 "result": "010000 ...
```

Why is this happening?

---

Example: https://chainquery.com/bitcoin-api/getblock/0000000000000000054AFA8DDFAE5908D9FE2DC157FD137C03F71C87439BCB6D/false

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Great question. I had to do some research to find out.

Currently version is actually 4 bytes. In the case of this block (and many other recent blocks, as it turns out) it's `01000020`. This is little endian, so when you reverse the bytes in hex it's:

```
0x20000001 = 536870913
```

Which in binary is:

```
00100000000000000000000000000001
```

It turns out that the bits here follow the [BIP0009 spec](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0009.mediawiki). You can get a more user-friendly explanation of [BIP0009 here](https://rusty.ozlabs.org/?p=576). Essentially, BIP0009 specifies that version bits are to be used to signal support for a soft-fork. In this particular case by using that that extra "1" at the end, the miner that mined this block is expressing support for [BIP0112](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0112.mediawiki) otherwise known as OP_CHECKSEQUENCEVERIFY.